# Oбработчик событий JavaScripts is null

Tags: javascript, html, события, javascript-events

Друзья есть такой вопрос: `html` страницы **`page1.html`** и **`page2.html`** подключаются на один внешний файл `js` с помощью `src` атрибута `(src="app.js")`.

В **`page1.html`** выводится ошибка, что  `two.addEventListener is "null"`.
И в  **`page2.html`**  `one.addEventListener is "null"` тоже.

Помогите разобраться с вопросом.

Заранее Спасибо.

**page1.html**

```
<span id="one"></span>
```

**page2.html**

```
<span id="two"></span>
```

**app.js**

```
const one = document.querySelector('#one');

one.addEventListener('click',function(){
     alert("page1");
});

const two = document.querySelector('#two');

two.addEventListener('click',function(){
     alert("page2");
});
```

Comment: очевидно что `one` нет на странице `two`, а `two` нет так странице `one`... и способ подключения на это никак не влияет, js кушает то, что ему дают, а не то, что где-то есть

Comment: Знаю это можно решить с помощью серверных языков..Но могут быть и другие решения

Comment: да, решение очень простое: `if (!one) return;` & `if (!two) return;` (это два разных `if`, если что, не пихайте это в один)

Comment: Спасибо не задумался

Comment: не за что, желаю успехов

Comment: Спасибо большое